# Extended WPF Toolkit Datagrid allow new rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) and its DataGridControl.

How can I allow the user to add a new row (it should be there from the start) so the view is not only editable, but the sourceBinding can have items added?

This is my xaml so far:

```
    <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="_dataGrid" 
                        MaxHeight="400"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_demo, Path=Orders, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        AutoCreateColumns="True">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
            <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
                <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
            </xcdg:TableflowView>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>

    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

I thought that `AutoCreateColumns="True"` should allow that, but it doesn't.

How do I get my DataGridControl to have a new line where a user can add new data?

**EDIT:**

My code behind looks like this (its only to figure out how this works:)

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      this.Orders = new List<Pocothing>();
      Orders.Add(new Pocothing(){NumWat = 1, Watwat = "wut1", Watwatwat = "haha!"});
      Orders.Add(new Pocothing(){NumWat = 2, Watwat = "wut2", Watwatwat = "haha!"});
      Orders.Add(new Pocothing(){NumWat = 3, Watwat = "wut3", Watwatwat = "haha!"});
      Orders.Add(new Pocothing(){NumWat = 4, Watwat = "wut4", Watwatwat = "haha!"});
      Orders.Add(new Pocothing(){NumWat = 3, Watwat = "wut5", Watwatwat = "haha!"});
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Pocothing
    {
      public int NumWat { get; set; }
      public string Watwat { get; set; }
      public string Watwatwat { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Pocothing> Orders { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I just found out, sadly, **you can't**.

They require you to buy the XCEED Datagrid for wpf:

> Xceed DataGrid for WPF includes the following additional features:
>
> - Master / Detail View
> - Tree Grid View
> - Card View
> - 3D View
> - Filter Row
> - **Insertion Row**
> - ...

Meaning that the insertion row which is a new row for the user to enter new data rows is not included in the free version.